# how to get width in pixels of view with android:layout_width="wrap_content"?

Tags: android, xml, layout, height, width

I have view, which have layout_width="wrap_content". If i use view.getWidth() in code, it returns 0. :-(
How can I convert width of view "wrap_content" to pixels?

Answer (score 5):

You could try `getMeasuredWidth` instead. but if it returns 0, that means the View is not ready when you try to measure it. try to make the call later. Like in a thread you poste when onCreate is finished

Answer (score 3):

it depends when are you calling view.getWidth() .The result will always be 0 if the view is not visible [onCreate , onResume] .

Try to call view.getWidth in

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // call get width here

}
```

Hope this will help .

Answer (score 1):

```
Button b = (Button) yourView.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
System.out.println("b.getMeasuredHeight() = "+b.getMeasuredHeight());
System.out.println("b.getMeasuredWidth() + "+ b.getMeasuredWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

- call view.getWidth in view.post()
- call view.getWidth in view.getViewTreeObserver().addGlobalLayoutListener()

Remember do not call view.getWidth() directly in onCreate(), cause the measuring process is not performed yet, where you can only get 0 returned by getWidth().